# oracle apex ords_metadata user missing

Tags: weblogic, oracle-rest-data-services

i have configure the ords on weblogic server, after installing the ords on weblogic , ords_metadata user missing oracle database .

i already tried with below query, but still ords_detadata user is missing . java -jar ords.war install advanced

Please help me with below issue.

i have configure the ords on weblogic server, after installing the ords on weblogic , ords_metadata user missing oracle database .

i already tried with below query, but still ords_detadata user is missing . java -jar ords.war install advanced

Comment: Well, when you ran this command, did you specify the proper database connection and user/pwd? can you paste the log of the session (i.e. what you have on the screen, and pleas eno images or links, copy-and-paste the text.